# Cyrillic symbols show as question marks. Content-Type:text/xml;charset=windows-1251;

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I know it's kinda popular question, but still I didn't find any solution.

So I am getting the xml file as the response from api, but Cyrillic symbols represents as question marks.

[image]

I have tried to convert source array of bytes using `Encoding` class.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
   var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uriBuilder.Uri);
   var responseBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
   var responseText = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(responseBytes);
   var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
   var unicode = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(responseBytes);
   var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes);
   var defaultt = Encoding.Default.GetString(responseBytes);
}
```

But still there is no luck.

Charset in response:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=windows-1251;
```

Could anyone suggest any solutions please ?

**Update**:
the answer is my comment below

Comment: What are you using to view results?  I do not think it is the deserialize, it is the viewer.

Comment: @jdweng it's Rider from JetBrains

Comment: It looks like a console window.  So you have to set the properties of the console to match the encoding.  Note sure if you change default encoding if that will help.  See : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-individual-file-encoding.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
var result = encoding.GetString(responseBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netcore-3.1) you can use `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(responseBytes);` to get the desired encoding.

Keep in mind that the operating system needs to support the code page.

Answer (score 0):

[windows-10-terminal-encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/1170656/windows-10-terminal-encoding)

View the current code page:

**chcp**

Change the code page to Unicode/1251:

**chcp 1251**